# Load Enum into a Camel header

Tags: enums, apache-camel, blueprint

I have the following class including an enumeration:

```
package com.xxx.enumeration;

public class Message {
    public enum Severity {
        INFO, ERROR, WARNING;
    }
}
```

**How can I create a Camel header in blueprint having the ERROR value?**

I tried to do the following

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelLogSeverity">
    <simple>${type:com.xxx.enumeration.Message.Severity.ERROR}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

but I am getting an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find type com.xxx.enumeration.Message.Severity.ERROR
```

If I put the Enum out of the class it works! But how can I refer to an Enum which is a Java class?

Thanks!

Comment: Try use Java's $ for sub classes, eg `...Severity$ERROR`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ClausIbsen . I used Java's $ and it worked! ...Message$Severity.ERROR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting comment as an answer so you can mark this as answered.

use Java's `$` for sub classes, so it would be

```
<simple>${type:com.xxx.enumeration.Message$Severity.ERROR}</simple>
```